# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined But it works

Tags: vue.js, axios

An odd one here. I am using Vue.js with a php back end. and I send the following:

```
validateEmail(){                        
        if(!this.emailModel.loading && this.$refs.emailForm.validate())            
        {                
            this.emailModel.loading = true;
            var url = 'https://exampleurl' + this.emailModel.email;
            axios.get(url).then((response) => {                                   
                    if(response.data.success == true)
                    {                            
                        this.companyModel.companyName = response.data.name;
                        this.companyModel.readOnly = true;
                        this.emailModel.loading = false;                            
                        this.$refs.wizard.changeTab(0,2);
                    }   
                    else
                    {                            
                        this.emailModel.loading = false;
                        this.$refs.wizard.changeTab(0,1);
                    }                     
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                    console.error(e);
                })                
        }   
        else
        {
            return false;
        }         
    },
```

And it works! As in the email is sent to the server which looks up the domain and returns a company name if there is one. The name is filled in the input and the input is set to read only. So everything appears fine, but I keep getting:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

found in

---> <FormWizard>
       <Register> at src/views/Register.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root> warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1884 globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879 handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839 invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1862 invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179 original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6911 vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at s (vue-form-wizard.js?fc12:1)
    at VueComponent.validateBeforeChange (vue-form-wizard.js?fc12:1)
    at VueComponent.beforeTabChange (vue-form-wizard.js?fc12:1)
    at VueComponent.nextTab (vue-form-wizard.js?fc12:1)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at HTMLSpanElement.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179)
    at HTMLSpanElement.original._wrapper (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6911)
```

I don't like errors in code, nor just catching them without understanding what is the cause. Anyone able to educate me and help solve this!

Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: error in "v-on handler" ---- FormWizard --- "validateBeforeChange" --- maybe you're looking at the wrong function for the .then error?

Comment: @Cody G The "v-on handler" calls the validateEmail.
<tab-content title="User Details" :before-change="validateEmail"> 
But I had considered this was being called multiple times hence adding the "!this.emailModel.loading" in to stop any repeats. If I comment out the Axios code the error goes away but obviously, the details are never populated.

Comment: No. I just ran a consle.log(url) to confirm, and it's correct, but also as mentioned the function is working, the company names are being returned and variables are being correctly filled... This is a really odd one!

Comment: Since no one else has really answered, I really doubt `axios.get(url).then` is  is undefined. I would set up a conditional breakpoint on that line (condition: `axios.get(url).then === undefined`) and see why it is the case, i.e. why does `axios.get(url)` not return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

before-change event expects a Promise to return, so you need to wrap your code inside a Promise function and call `resolve()` when validations are passed.

```
validateEmail(){                        
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

        if(!this.emailModel.loading && this.$refs.emailForm.validate())            
        {                
            this.emailModel.loading = true;
            var url = 'https://exampleurl' + this.emailModel.email;
            axios.get(url).then((response) => {                                   
                    if(response.data.success == true)
                    {                            
                        this.companyModel.companyName = response.data.name;
                        this.companyModel.readOnly = true;
                        this.emailModel.loading = false;
                        resolve();                            
                        this.$refs.wizard.changeTab(0,2);
                    }   
                    else
                    {                            
                        this.emailModel.loading = false;
                        resolve();
                        this.$refs.wizard.changeTab(0,1);
                    }                     
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                    console.error(e);
                })                
        }   
        else
        {
            reject();
            return false;
        }
    });         
},
```